# How to handle a Rails query causing massive delays

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I'm using the query below that is then being used as a submenu and it's causing significant loading issues. I've put it in the application_helper for the time being.

```
def category_level
 Connector::Category.includes(:products).group_by(&:parent_category_id)
end
```

Then it's being displayed on the home page with the following:

```
<ul class="list-style-upper">
 <% category_level[nil].each do |root| %>
   <%= render 'products/submenu/category_item', category: root %>
 <% end %>
</ul>
```

Which redirects to

```
<li class="list-one">
  <a href="#"><%= category.name %><p><%= category.products.count %></p></a>
  <% if category_level[category.id].present? %>
 <ul class="list-style-upper-sub">
   <% category_level[category.id].each do |child| %>
     <%= render 'products/submenu/category_item', category: child %>
   <% end %>
 </ul>
 <% end %>
</li>
```

The issue is that there are typically around 30,000 products. Is there a way to build out the results and store them for display?

Comment: Your main problem is probably the use of `.group_by(&: parent_category_id)` and not `.group(:parent_category_id)`. `group_by` pulls all the records out of the DB into memory and iterates through them in Ruby. This is extremely ineffective. `.group` adds a GROUP BY statement and groups the records in the database.

Comment: Switching to .group results in The method .group() must contain arguments

Comment: Yes, you have to actually tell it which column you need to group the results by.

Comment: Yeah I thought I could do a simple Connector::Category.includes(:products).group(:parent_category_id). But it ends up with PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "connector_categories.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function